Is it permissible to cut toenails on Thursday
I saw that it is customary not to cut fingernails on Thursday. The Mishnah Berura  (סימן רס סק"ו ובשער הציון שם) wrote in the name of Eliya Rabbah, that they are careful not to cut nails on Thursday, because they start growing back and growing on the third day after they were cut, and if so it is not tikkun honor for Shabbat that they come back out on Shabbat.
And the question: both according to Kabbalah and according to reality and medical knowledge, toenails grow more slowly than fingernails, so they are most likely to start growing after Shabbat, so is it permissible to cut toenails on Thursday?

"According to Kabbalah toenails [...] grow more slowly than fingernails" How do you know this?

They might grow slower, but they still start growing on the third day

I wonder if science confirms nails don't start growing right away - I am not sure why they would "wait" 2 days to start growing again

@mbloch nails and hair grow constantly

The opinion of Eliah Rabbah is middas chassidus - going beyond the letter of the law in positive mitzvos.  It is something reserved for very pious people as there are different levels of observance.

What halacha is violated because nails grow on Shabbos?

@YDJ It's about respect for Shabbos. Cutting your nails just in time for them to regrow on Shabbos is like changing out your clean shirt for a dirty one.

@shmosel it's a very strange comparison. I gave you +1 for the source, but your comparison is inappropriate: nobody sees toenails, and your source shows that finger nails are cut on Friday. When people take shower before Shabbos they clean fingernails and toenails easily.

@YDJ I thought you were asking about fingernails. It's not clear if the same would apply to toenails.

@shmosel the issue is even more problematic. When we make havdalah, it's good to have bigger nails when seeing reflection of light. I don't have a source, but heard it from a serious learner.

"according to reality and medical knowledge, toenails grow more slowly than fingernails, so they are most likely to start growing after Shabbat" I think you'd be hard pressed to corroborate that with anything contemporary...

@Deuteronomy I think there's a pretty wide consensus that toenails grow slower than fingernails.

@shmosel that was not the point I was making. The rate of nail growth is not affected by trimming. It consistently grows at its own rate no matter the date or time of the last time one trimmed. The idea that it would "start growing after Shabbat" or at any other time is not at all aligned with "reality and medical knowledge"

@Deuteronomy Maybe it's that their growth becomes noticeable on the third day.

The same Mishnah Berurah recommends cutting toenails on Thursday:

והנכון שיקוץ מן הרגלים ביום ה' ומן הידים ביום ו'‏

However, Shulchan Aruch HaRav (260:2) seems to discourage it:

ויש נזהרין שלא לקץ אלא בערב שבת או בערב יום טוב, וקוצצין מן הרגלים
ביום ה' ומן הידים בערב שבת, אבל בשאר הימים אין קוצצין כלל, מטעם הידוע
להם.  ויש מקפידים שלא לטול צפרנים ביום ה', מפני  שהצפרנים מתחילין
לחזור ולצמוח ביום ג' לגלוחן, ואינם רוצים שיהיה זה בשבת:‏

